# deploying data from google cloud spanner database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to get data from my google cloud spanner into a web page. But i'm not familiar with cloud spanner. I created some tables and add data into them. Now i want to get them to my own web page

Comment: where is your web page running, what programing language are you using ?

Comment: i'm using php. the web page is still on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/php), where it is explained step by step the process of working with cloud spanner with php.

```
1.Create a Cloud Spanner instance and database.
2.Write, read, and execute SQL queries on data in the database.
3.Update the database schema.
4.Update data using a read-write transaction.
5.Add a secondary index to the database.
6.Use the index to read and execute SQL queries on data.
7.Retrieve data using a read-only transaction.
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted for better visibility for the community.